# Local ring and zero divisors

Tags: commutative-algebra, local-rings

> Let $(R,\mathfrak m)$ be a Noetherian local ring. Suppose that all $x$ belonging to $\mathfrak m-\mathfrak m^2$ are zero divisors. Show that all elements of $\mathfrak m$ are zero divisors.

My progress:

My idea is to see that the set of zero divisors is equal to the union of the associated primes of the ideal zero, obtained from the minimal primary decomposition of the ideal zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's useful to promote my comments on Pete Clark's answer to a new answer.

We know that the set of zero divisors of $R$ is equal to the union of the associated primes of $R$. Moreover, the set $\operatorname{Ass}(R)$ of associated primes is finite. We have $$\mathfrak m=\mathfrak m^2\cup(\mathfrak m-\mathfrak m^2)\subseteq\mathfrak m^2\cup\bigcup_{\mathfrak p\in\operatorname{Ass}(R)}\mathfrak p.$$ From [prime avoidance lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_avoidance_lemma) we learn that $\mathfrak m$ is contained in one of the ideals of the union, so $\mathfrak m\subseteq\mathfrak m^2$ or $\mathfrak m\subseteq\mathfrak p$ for some $\mathfrak p\in\operatorname{Ass}(R)$.
In the first case $\mathfrak m=0$ by Nakayama, and this is a contradiction with the hypothesis which tacitly assumes $\mathfrak m\ne\mathfrak m^2$.
In the second case we get $\mathfrak m\in\operatorname{Ass}(R)$, and therefore there is a nonzero element $x$ of $R$ with $x\mathfrak m=0$, so $\mathfrak m$ consists of zerodivisors, and we are done.

Answer (score 4):

In fact, under the given hypothesis there is a nonzero element $x$ of $R$ with
$x \mathfrak{m} = \{0\}$.  This is proved in Lemma 5.85 of T.Y. Lam's GTM *Lectures on Modules and Rings*.  Lam's proof is reproduced in Corollary 10.8 of [these notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/integral.pdf).

Comment: @NECing, in what possible way this does not answer the question?!

Comment: You mentioned earlier that the problem can be solved by using the Krull Intersection Theorem, but it is not clear to me how. Could you elaborate a little bit further?

Comment: thanks very much Pete L.Clark

Comment: I tried used Krull Intersection Theorem, but I've could

Comment: with the hint of Pete L.Clark, I could resolving the exercise

Comment: First of all, there is no difference between "all elements of $m$ are zerodivisors" and "there is a nonzero element $x$ of $R$ with $xm=\{0\}$", that is, they are equivalent. Second, the question is a trivial consequence of the [prime avoidance lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_avoidance_lemma).

Comment: @user26857: the answer -- which yes, uses prime avoidance -- shows that the weaker condition that you quote implies the stronger one, so sure, they're equivalent under the hypotheses given.  The same conclusion holds for any maximal ideal in a Noetherian ring.  But in a non-Noetherian local ring I'm not sure the weaker condition implies the stronger one: that seems to be a "difference".

Comment: I have to admit that I didn't get what has the non-Noetherian case to do with the question and the quoted answer. (Sure, the quoted claims in my previous comment aren't equivalent in the non-Noetherian case as a well chosen quotient of the polynomial ring in countable many indeterminates over a field shows us.) I've tried only to point out that there is no need to give references for such trivial results. (Unfortunately the question is closed, so I didn't have the possibility to post my own answer, that's why I've decided to comment here.)

Comment: @user26857: My point is that I don't really understand your comment that there is "no difference" between the conditions: yes, that's what the answer shows.  About the result itself: as I said, it appears in a GTM by T.Y. Lam.  If you know a solution which is significantly easier than Lam's, I'd be interested to see it.

Comment: The present question gives us some hypotheses, one of them being that the ring is noetherian. In this frame, there is no difference indeed. Well, I've checked the Lam's proof right now and maybe he missed that $m=m^2\cup(m-m^2)\subseteq m^2\cup\{\text{a finite union of primes}\}$ and/or the version of prime avoidance assuming that *two* ideals in the union can be non-prime, or simply he wanted to give a self-contained proof which I find rather boring.

Comment: @user268574: Okay, good!  Your proof is indeed easier.  I will change the argument in my notes.  If you want to write to me to identify yourself, I will acknowledge your help.  (I still don't think that the proof is *trivial*: we have to apply Nakayama's Lemma, prime avoidance and then do *something*.  But whether something is trivial or not is one of the things least worth arguing about that I can think of.  You are certainly entitled to your opinion.)